# Как узнать об изменении значения в делегате для текущей ячейки до изменений в модели?

Tags: qt, gui

Есть делегат для отображения `QComboBox`, он наследуется от `QStyledItemDelegate`. 
Переопределены методы `setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index)`, `setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model,const QModelIndex &index) const`, `createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option , const QModelIndex & index ) const`. 
Также определена собственная модель на основе `QAbstractTableModel`.

Пользователь может менять выбранное значение в комбобоксе, но оно передастся в модель только когда он выйдет из режима редактирования. И только тогда я смогу получить от модели сигнал `dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &bottomRight)`. 
Задача состоит в том, чтобы на лету менять набор значений другого делегата-комбобокса, при изменении текущего выбранного пункта в первом комбобоксе.

Т.к. первый делегат установлен на всю колонку в `QTableView`, то при добавлении в `createEditor connect(editor, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(slotChanged(int)))` и отправке сигнала в слоте `slotChanged(int)` - это происходит для всех комбобоксов в колонке. 
Мне же нужно это отслеживать только для текущего комбобокса, как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: Должны ли затрагиваться (перезаписываться новым значением) данные модели в процессе редактирования текущего значения делегата (раскрывающегося списка)?

Comment: @alexis031182 т.к. функции отмены изменения текущего значения списка не предусмотрено, и при выходе из режима редактирования оно все равно запишется в модель. тогда по идее можно сразу перезаписывать значение в модели

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то сигнал `QComboBox::editTextChanged(const QString&)` нужно цеплять к какому-нибудь произвольному слоту класса делегата. В этом слоте нужно получить через `qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(sender())` тот раскрывающийся список, что испустил сигнал, чтобы затем записать данные в модель.

Однако перед этим необходимо с ассоциировать каждый `QComboBox` определённой строке табличной модели. Тогда в методе делегата:

```
createEditor(QWidget*, const QStyleOptionViewItem&, const QModelIndex&)
```

необходимо вновь создаваемому экземпляру `QComboBox` присвоить номер строки из `QModelIndex` например так:

```
QWidget *MyDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent
    , const QStyleOptionViewItem &option
    , const QModelIndex &index) const {

    QComboBox *cbox = new QComboBox(parent);
    cbox->setProperty("model-row", index.row());
    return cbox;
}
```

Если модель SQL, то тут можно и к ключевому полю таблицы привязаться вместо индекса строки.

Соответственно теперь, если произвольный слот получит сигнал об изменении текста в одном из раскрывающихся списков, то сможет однозначно определить, в каком именно:

```
void MyDelegate::onEditTextChanged(const QString &text) {
    QComboBox *cbox = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(sender());
    if(cbox == Q_NULLPTR) return; // Паранойя.

    const int row = cbox->property("model-row").toInt();
    //...
}
```

Далее, имея индекс строки, можно уже работать с моделью. Однако произвольный слот не содержит на неё указатель. Здесь можно пойти различно: сохранять указатель на модель в каком-нибудь приватном члене класса делегата, либо точно также через свойства объекта в `QVariant` передавать этот указатель на саму модель.

Comment: спасибо. а как можно заменить содержимое списка второго комбобокса только в одной ячейке? у делегата-комбобокса есть метод установки списка. itemDelegateForColumn не подойдет, т.к. изменится список у всей колонки, а нужно только в текущей строке. Предположим, во view я получаю сигнал dataChanged от модели, как мне дальше получить делегата именно для нужной ячейки?

Comment: @Emm , тогда нужно метод установки списка модернизировать таким образом, чтобы сохранялся собственный список для каждой отдельной строки. Заведите в делегате, например, `QMap<int,QStringList>`. Таким образом, при выводе QComboBox можно будет показать отдельный список. А например по ключу "-1" можно хранить общий для всех строк список по умолчанию.